# How can i select flatlist items and highlights items in react-native using onPress function?

Tags: react-native

I don't know how to select flatlist items on onPress and display highlight the flatlist items onPress function using flatlist.
In this flatlist i am fettching data using package.js file and using class method

**Code**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Stylesheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import PACKAGE from './Package'

export default class extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selected: '',
    }
 
 _OnPress =() =>{
 /**/ 
 }

 <FlatList
          data={PACKAGE}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingRight: 20 }}
          horizontal
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({ item, separators }) => (
            <View style={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.myAccountPriceInfo, { backgroundColor: item.color }]}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={[styles.priceText, { color: item.textColor }]}>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.priceDetail}>
                  <Text style={[styles.numText, { color: item.textColor }]}>from </Text>
                  <Text style={[styles.dollarText, { color: item.textColor }]}>$</Text>
                  <Text style={[styles.priceNumText, { color: item.textColor }]}>{item.cost}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )}
        />
}
```

Comment: where do you want to display the highlight item?

Comment: I want to highlight flatlist touchable items on flatlist.Like When a user selects an item in the flatlist, they can see that the item has been selected.So can you please help this query and thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Can a user select multiple item or just one?

Comment: can you also give the example of Package data structure?

Comment: User can select just One item at a time.

Comment: check the code in the answer region.

Comment: const Packages = [
    {
      name: 'Bike\nMAINTENANCE',
      color: 'rgba(0, 169, 104, 1)',
      textColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
      cost: '64'
    },
    {
      name: 'Bike\nServices',
      color: 'rgba(0, 169, 104, 1)',
      textColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
      cost: '32'
    },]
export default Packages

Comment: This is the package examples

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `_OnPress` function like this.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Stylesheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import PACKAGE from './Package'

export default class extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selected: null,
    }

 renderItem = ({ item, separators }) => {
   // you can know here whether the item is selected or not.
   const isSelected = item.name === this.selected.selectedItem;

   return ( 
      <View style={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={[
            styles.myAccountPriceInfo, { backgroundColor: item.color },
            // you could highlight your selected item like this.
            isSelected && styles.highlightSelected
          ]}
          // let the state know which item has been selected
          onPress={() => this.setState(item.name)}
        >
          <View>
            <Text style={[styles.priceText, { color: item.textColor }]}>{item.name}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.priceDetail}>
            <Text style={[styles.numText, { color: item.textColor }]}>from </Text>
            <Text style={[styles.dollarText, { color: item.textColor }]}>$</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.priceNumText, { color: item.textColor }]}>{item.cost}</Text>
          </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
   )
 }

  return ( 
    <FlatList
      data={PACKAGE}
      contentContainerStyle={{ paddingRight: 20 }}
      horizontal
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
  )
}
```